# mongodb query on object type of field

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i have a collection of records where a particular field does not conform to a single data type.
it contains different data types in each record

something like this

```
{"field1":ObjectId("53de"),"field2":string}
{"field1":string,"field2":string}
{"field1":NumberLong(123),"field2":string}
```

i would like to query only for the records in which the field1 contains string data types.
is there a way in which i could query for particular data types in field1?

something like

```
db.collection.find({field1:{$regex:"some string format"}})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `$type` operator to query attributes against specific types:

```
db.collection.find( { "field1": { $type : 2 } } )
```

Take a look at the [docs for `$type`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) - a string value is represented by the integer 2.

And then in order to change those values you could use an update statement together with a query on the `$type`. Here I'm changing the `field1` attribute to be an `ObjectId()`.

```
db.collection.update( 
  { "field1": { $type : 2 } }, 
  { "$set": {
    "field1": ObjectId() 
  }  } 
)
```

Comment: Happy to be of assistance :)